# Proof by induction (in terms of sums)

Tags: proof-verification, induction

Using induction, prove that:

(1-x)Ex^i=1-x^n

In this question, E is the summation symbol, going from i=0 to n-1.

I have gotten all the way to the inductive step but I am unsure how to re arrange the final part to get to 1-x^(k+1)

Any help is appreciated

Comment: To be clear, do you mean $(1-x)\sum\limits_{i=0}^{n-1}x^i = 1-x^n$?

Comment: [Here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) is a primer on how to correctly type mathematics on this site using $\LaTeX$ and MathJax so you don't have to use confusing and incorrect notation like you did.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose for some $k \in \mathbb{N}$ we have $(1 - x)\sum_{i = 0}^{k - 1} x^i= 1- x^k$. Then 
\begin{align}
(1 - x)\sum_{i = 0}^k x^i &= (1 - x)\sum_{i = 0}^{k - 1} x^i + (1-x)x^k \\
&= (1-x^k) + (1-x)x^k && \text{By the inductive hypothesis}\\
&= 1 - x^k + x^k - x^{k + 1} 
\\&= 1 - x^{k + 1}
\end{align}
This completes the inductive step.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Try distributing the multiplication. For finite sums, $(a-b)\sum c_i = \sum ac_i - \sum bc_i$.

Do you see that there will be cancellation of many terms in this expansion of your expression?

Answer (score 0):

for $n+1$, you get

$$(1-x)(\frac {1-x^n}{1-x}+x^n)=$$

$$1-x^n+x^n-x^{n+1}=1-x^{n+1} $$

Answer (score 0):

Since you said that you have gone to the inductive step already:

HINT:

$$
(1-x)\sum_{i=0}^{n}x^i = (1-x)\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}x^i + (1-x)x^n
$$